# Django-filter additional filtering

Tags: python, django, django-filter

There is a model structure of the following form

```
class Industry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    industry = models.ForeignKey('Industry', null=True, blank=True)

class Franchise(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category')
    industries = models.ManyToManyField('Industry')
```

And I have a regular filter:

```
class FranchiseFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    industries = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Industry.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    )
    categories = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Category.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    )
```

the idea is to implement a filter so that when selecting the industries without selecting its categories displays all franchises of selected industry (without categories matching)

I have implemented additional filter

```
class CategoryMultipleChoceFilter(django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        categories_list = []
        categories_list.extend(value.values_list('id', flat=True))

        if value:
            industries = self.parent.data.getlist('industries')

            for industry_pk in industries:
                industry_instance = Industry.objects.filter(pk=industry, category__in=value)
                if not industry_instance.exists():
                    category = Category.objects.filter(industry=industry_pk)
                    categories_list.extend(category.values_list('id', flat=True))

        return super().filter(qs, categories_list)
```

for "categories" field:

```
class FranchiseFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    ...
    categories = CategoryMultipleChoceFilter(
        queryset=Category.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    )
```

this solution works, but I'm not sure that it is correct. perhaps there is a more elegant solution?